# Any plugin or Script to integrate ajax selection module into WordPress page

Tags: ajax

I am creating a WebHosting site using WordPress. It needs a custom feature selection module to add remove amountof disk space etc.

In [this particular website](http://www.instance.io) that I like <sup>1)</sup>, there is a custom "instance selection"-module that adds ram space etc. the site is WordPress powered.

Is there any plugin or script to get the same functionality like that ?

<sup>1) It's not the OPs site.</sup>

Comment: Just a sidenote: _"Wien's #1 Choice In Cloud Computing."_ sounds nice, but in some European countries, it's illegal to use such sentences, if you can't proof it.

Comment: That's not my site btw. And yeah that's a bit irritating because it uses geo location stuff to say it is the best in users area.

I will never have such a message in mine though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Site you linked is not using Ajax to update its simply a custom designed [**`jQuery UI Slider`**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/)  and if you look at the source of the page more specifically at the included `server-order.js` you can see that all of the prices are set in an array and there is no Ajax going on there simply JavaScript.

Comment: Is it possible to link jquery based link to a custom page ? Ex: when they make their choice all that has to be sent to a domain.com/billing page where the choices must remain the same.

Comment: yes look for jqurey ajax,post,get,getJson methods